# Empty object being sent to DB

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, express

I'm writing a basic search function to query a postgresql db. When I'm running it and with console.logs up, I keep seeing that it's sending and returning a 200, however the object it is sending is blank. Below is my function followed by my curl command I'm sending. When I run the search function during the DB seed, it's able to find what I'm looking for.

curl http://localhost:5000/api/company/parts/GCS

```
companyRouter.get("/parts/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const partNumber = req.body;
  console.log("request 19", partNumber, req.body);
  try {
    const part = await searchPartsNumber(partNumber);
    res.send({ part });
  } catch ({ name, message }) {
    next({ name, message });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION -1:

you are not passing any body to the request . you are passing a url parameter. that's why your body is an empty object. if you want to get the parameter ( in your case GCS ) in your server you should do something like this

```
const partNumber = req.param('id');
```

SOLUTION - 2

otherwise if you want to pass body using curl you should modify your request like this.

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"partNumber":"YOUR_PART_NUMBER"}' \
  http://localhost:5000/api/company/parts/GCS
```

and as req.body is an object. you should extract your partNumber like this

`const {partNumber} = req.body;`

Comment: I had that originally, in the pursuit of trying to find the resolution, I had taken away the { } around partNumber, destructuring it gives me the same results, except my console.log shows partNumber as undefined now.

Comment: can you share what it prints when you console.log your req.body ?

Comment: ```request 19 undefined {}
searching undefined <--this is from my index in the db file
[]
GET /api/company/parts/GCS 200 21.830 ms - 11```

Comment: so clearly your req.body has not arrived properly from your frontend. the error is not in your provided code

Comment: That's the problem, I'm only using a curl command currently, I'm not even using a function off the front end.

If I run "curl http://localhost:5000/api/company/parts" for example, I get the full listing of my database of parts, it's when I start using the section I want to search through the database for using something like "curl http://localhost:5000/api/company/parts/GCS(the part number) that I'm not seeing it send anything.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for your assistance!

Comment: Sorry didn't think about it!

side note, req.param is showing as deprecated, but a quick swap to req.params.id fixed the deprecation - however without your answer I'd never have figured that out.